# Create Xcode project from Unity with ARC mode enable

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am using Unity 4.6.3 with the vuforia sdk to create an augmented reality project for xcode, and when I open the project and add some of my libraries Xcode put this kind of error.

`@synthesize of 'weak' property is only allowed in ARC or GC mode`

I searched how to convert my project to ARC mode in Xcode but I got even more errors from the unity libraries so I was wondering if there is a way to create my project from unity with ARC mode on.

Comment: It should be on by default.

Comment: ARC mode would certainly be "on".  Did you mean you want to turn it off?  it's hard to believe that would be possible - the zillion lines of code unity generates would all need ARC.  If you wanted to "turn it off" (for some reason) perhaps just do so in Xcode?

Comment: To put it off http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/888319/ios-disable-arc-on-xcode-projects.html but I think it is affecting plug ins.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answers, perhaps I should have put more details I will edit my question